# Licensing Adobe AIR app - how to

Tags: android, air, licensing, copy-protection, air-native-extension

Previously I build two apps. The free app have truncated functional and promoting the paid app. Paid application is defended by Copy Protection of Android Market.

Now I installed the native extention. If I get status == LicenseStatus.LICENSED in the paid app, I authorize access to the full functionality, right?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Zarqon](http://zarqon.net/). Also read the article, "Overcoming FUD" by Cliff Hall on this [Page](http://zarqon.net/learn-more.html).